# What does spectral flux density mean "per wavelength"?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, spectroscopy, si-units

If I understand correctly the term "spectral flux density" describes radiant flux for a given wavelength, right?

Like the given wavelength is the $\nu$ in:

$$F(\mathbf{x},t;\nu)=\oint_\Omega I(\mathbf{x},t;\hat{\mathbf{n}},\nu)\hat{\mathbf{n}}\,d\omega(\hat{\mathbf{n}})$$

For example, the EM wavelength of green light is about $500\,\mathrm{nm}$.

So can we talk about the spectral flux density $D$ of green light at a given point on a surface?  Or have I got it wrong?

If I've got it right - what I don't understand is why is it per unit meter wavelength?  Do we need to divide through by $500 \times 10^9$ to get the value of D in SI units?

Let's take a concrete example: say there are $1000\,\mathrm{lx}$ (ie $1000\,\mathrm{lm/m^2}$) of uniformly white light hitting a surface.  What is the spectral flux density of green light in the SI unit of $\mathrm{Wm^{-3}}$?

Comment: What has the equation (written in terms of frequency) got to do with the question?

Comment: I'm thinking spectral flux density would usually be watts per square meter (of incident area) per Hertz (of optical bandwidth).

Comment: "White light" is a very ambiguous term for a physicist. A lot of different spectra look white due to metamerism. And, to add to the confusion, white color is also not unique due to different color temperatures of the white point one may choose. What exactly do you mean by "uniformly white light"?

Comment: @ProfRob: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_flux_density#Vector_definition_of_flux_density_-_'full_spherical_flux_density'

Comment: @RogerWood: I believe the SI unit is formally Wm^-3.  I assumed the extra per meter is for wavelength.  See above link.

Comment: @Ruslan:  I mean that the spectral flux density is uniform over the visible range.  For any wavelengths A and B in the visible range, spectral_flux_density(A) = spectral_flux_density(B).  (Although that may be confusing if you are indeed supposed to divide through by the wavelength - which is my main question)

Comment: @RogerWood: Oh wait do you mean "optical bandwidth" as in it is the width of a segment in the EM spectrum, and not an absolute wavelength.  That is actually making more sense now.

Comment: White light as perceived and measured in lumens doesn't have a uniform flux density. Flux density expressed per unit of wavelength is different to flux density expressed per unit frequency.

Comment: It means that the quantity Q you are looking at is actually $Q=dF/d\lambda$ of another quantity F, with wavelength $\lambda$.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos I'm an EE, not a physicist, so I automatically think of spectral density per Hz and as the Fourier transform of autocorrelation function.  Also I would use f or omega for frequency,not nu.  Looking at the Wiki article, I understand the equation now. It can be interpreted as either having units of watts/Hz or Watts per wavelength-increment, for a given solid angle, big-omega.  I'm used to radio frequencies so "per wavelength increment" seems a weird way of expressing spectral density to me, but I suppose for light. nanometers are more familiar and measurable units than TeraHertz

Comment: @AndrewTomazos the word density does lead to a lot of confusion.  I guess it's important to specify if it's per Hz or per wavelength-increment and also if it's per unit solid-angle or per unit area.  Or is it both of these together (e.g. the W/m^3). The Wiki article is not very helpful in that respect.

Comment: You asked "the term 'spectral flux density' describes radiant flux for a given wavelength, right?"  Is it possible you are confusing "flux density" with flux?  The term "flux density" usually describes [irradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance), or flux (W) through a surface (m^2), with common units of W / m^2.  Therefore "_spectral_ flux density" is irradiance per wavelength, commonly in units of W / m^2 / nm.

Comment: @SeanSkelly: Flux density describes flux at a certain point on a surface (the derivative of flux per surface), just like density describes mass at some point in a volume (the derivative of mass per volume).  What was confusing me was the spectral aspect, which actually turned out to be the same thing (the flux density at some wavelength - the derivate of flux density per wavelength).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spectral flux density is required because the number of photons (or amount of energy) at some precise wavelength is zero. You have to integrate over a finite range of wavelengths to get a finite flux. The thing that is integrated over a range of wavelengths must therefore be expressed per metre (or more conveniently per whatever unit of wavelength you are using). i.e. To work out the power received in total you have to integrate the flux density over a wavelength bandwidth.

It is difficult to answer your second question which mixes up units of perceived brightness with physical units of power. It would depend on the conversion factor from lumens to Watts and what the actual spectrum of a perceived white light source was. But let's assume your white light is a scaled solar spectrum. Direct sunlight has about 100 lumens/W and a power per unit area of 1000 W/m$^2$, so your light source is about 1% as bright as direct sunlight.

The spectral flux density of direct sunlight peaks in the green at about 1.3 W/m$^2$ **per nm**, so your source would be 100 times fainter/smaller than that. If you then *really* want to express that as W/m$^3$, multiply by $10^9$ to get
$1.3\times 10^7$ W/m$^2$ per m (or W/m$^3$).

Comment: Yeah I think I get it now.  You are taking a derivative of flux over the domain of an infantesimaly small range of wavelengths surrounding the given wavelength - so the per unit wavelength in the SI unit is to reflect the denominator of that derivative.  (You don't need to divide through by the given absolute wavelength).

Answer (score 1):

The flux of green light over a "point" could be measured with a filter green light and a photoreceptor beside. As ProfRob comments, the probability of finding a photon with an exact frequency is zero, therefore we need to integrate over frequency or, what is equivalent, wavelength.

Mathematically speaking we can represent a photon either in the space-time domain or in the energy-momentum domain, a "pure" photon" of a single frequency would be represented in the momentum space as a delta and as a harmonic wave overall the space, however in the real world the photons do not behave that way, they move through specific regions of space with specific frequencies, but we can argue that neither the position nor the frequency of the real photons is a pure delta, that is the reason why a small detector filtering around a small range of green light frecuencies can detect photons.